# How to move ownership across unique_ptrs

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two smart-pointers:

```
Foo *p1 = new Foo;
Foo *p2 = new Foo;
std::unique_ptr<Foo> u1(p1);
std::unique_ptr<Foo> u2(p2);
```

Now I want `u1` to own `p2`. And I want `u2` to own nothing (or `nullptr`). Of cource, at the same time `p1` must be deleted gracefully.

What C++ code should I write to accomplish it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `std::move` to cast `u2` to an rvalue then use move assignment to "move" `u2` into `u1`:

```
u1 = std::move(u2);
```

After the move, `u2` will be `nullptr` although that is special case for `unique_ptr`, don't expect moved from objects to be in any particular state generally. And of course `p1` will be deleted gracefully.

I recommend you don't create `p1` or `p2` at all and never have any owning raw pointers:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> u1(new Foo);
```

Or better yet, in C++14:

```
auto u1 = std::make_unique<Foo>();
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is basically the description of move assignment for `unique_ptr`, modulo the deleter part (not relevant here):

```
u1 = std::move(u2);
```

Answer (score 3):

The two versions below will do the same thing:

```
u1 = std::move(u2);
```

and

```
u1.swap(u2);
u2.reset(nullptr);
```

although the first is more efficient. `u2` will hold a `nullptr` in both cases.

I'm also joining the chorus for using `std::make_unique` in C++14 (more efficient and in many cases, safer).